# i can't access my website from another computer in a LAN using xampp

Tags: php, apache, xampp, lan

Perhaps my question is repeated but I read other topics and their answers but none of them solve my problem. 
I turn off firewall in both computers and also create virtualhost in `vhost.conf` file . Also in `http.conf` I change listen line to `listen 80`.
I want to access `index.php` in file named **"test"** which direction to is `/htdoc/test`. My IP is `192.168.100.17` and remote computer IP is `192.168.100.16`.
When I type `192.168.100.17/test` in browser, there is no response.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Questions on **professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/tour).

Comment: @Qirel xampp usually is considered a development tool :-)

Comment: First make sure that the http server is actually running. Test that with the command line call `telnet localhost 80` on the system running xampp. If it fails to connect, then the apache http server is not even running. If it connects and replies like "Connected to ...", then this is fine and you have to try the same from the client system. If that fails you have a network routing issue.

Comment: thank you @arkascha , my problem solved :)